# How to pass itcl object from one class to another?

Tags: tcl, itcl

I have a 3 classes:  `A` , `B` and `C`, theye are all in the same namespace: `foo`. I create an instance of the `C` inside `A`:

```
set object [::foo::C \#auto $param] 
$b addObject $object ;#  b is a instance of the B
```

But inside B I cannot use the object:
It's said: invalid command name `C0`

How to create Itcl object and pass it from one class to another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the fully-qualified name of the object in this case.

```
$b addObject [namespace which $object]
```

As long as B doesn't expect an unqualified name, that should work fine. (If B wants to recover the unqualified name, use `namespace tail $fqn`.)