# itcl How to pass objects around to other objects

Tags: tcl, itcl

I'm just getting started with itcl and I have found [How to pass itcl object from one class to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18573872/how-to-pass-itcl-object-from-one-class-to-another) but that did not help me.

I have the following objects defined:

```
package require Itcl

namespace eval FEM {

   itcl::class Node {
       variable nid
       variable x
       variable y
       variable z

       constructor {{NID 0} {coordX 0} {coordY 0} {coordZ 0}} {
         set nid $NID
         set x $coordX
         set y $coordY
         set z $coordZ
         return $this}

       method is {nid coordX coordY coordZ}
       method printString  
      }

   itcl::body Node::is {NID coordX coordY coordZ} {
       set nid $NID  
       set x $coordX
       set y $coordY
       set z $coordZ}       

   itcl::body Node::printString {} {
       return "$nid $x $y $z"}

# #######################################################

   itcl::class CQUAD {
       variable eid
       variable pid
       variable node1
       variable node2
       variable node3
       variable node4

       constructor {{EID 0} {PID 0} {NODE1 0} {NODE2 0} {NODE3 0} {NODE4 0}} {
         set eid $EID
         set pid $PID
         set node1 $NODE1
         set node2 $NODE2
         set node3 $NODE3
         set node4 $NODE4
         return $this}

       method is {EID PID NODE1 NODE2 NODE3 NODE4}
       method printString  

      }  

   itcl::body CQUAD::is { EID PID NODE1 NODE2 NODE3 NODE4 } {
       set eid $EID
       set pid $PID  
       set node1 $NODE1
       set node2 $NODE2
       set node3 $NODE3
       set node4 $NODE4}       

   itcl::body CQUAD::printString {} {
       return "$eid $pid $node1 $node2 $node3 $node4"}
  }

}

# ########################################################
# Test  

for {set n 1} {$n <= 4} {incr n} {  
   set coord1 [expr {$n+1} ]
   set coord2 [expr {$n+2} ]
   set coord3 [expr {$n+3} ]   
   set NID N$n
   ::FEM::Node $NID $n $coord1 $coord2 $coord3
   puts "[$NID printString]"
 }

set PID 99
set EID 88
```

The following is wrong since `$N1` simply is `N1`  and not a "node" `N1`

```
::FEM::CQUAD MyQuad $EID $PID $N1 $N2 $N3 $N4
```

But how do I pass an object of type Node to an Object of type CQUAD ?
I also tried:

```
::FEM::CQUAD MyQuad $EID $PID $::FEM:Node::N1 $::FEM:Node::N2 $::FEM:Node::N3 $::FEM:Node::N4
```

Also, how do I delete an object? `unset $N1` is wrong `unset $::FEM::Node::N1` is also bogus

Final question: Assume that I have a CQUAD object with objects of type Node in it:
How could I eg get the y coordinate of Node2 of CQUAD 1 ?

Answer (score 2):

In Itcl (as in the rest of Tcl), you don't pass the object itself, you pass the *name* of the object which the consuming command resolves to a *reference* to the object.

Generally speaking, an object's name should be passed around as its fully-qualified name so that the names are understood everywhere in Tcl as meaning the same thing. You can get this for `N1` by using `namespace which N1`. (The exceptions to this are Tk widget names, which have to be in the global namespace, passed around unqualified, and always start with `.`.)

To delete an object (as opposed to a variable containing the name of an object) you use:

```
itcl::delete object $theObjectName
```

Note that Itcl objects are *not* garbage collected (but it is possible to simulate this in simple cases using a delete trace on a variable in a suitable stack frame; the `itcl::local` command makes this easier).

To access a *public* variable of an Itcl object, use [the `cget` method](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/Itcl4.0.0Cmd/class.htm#M22) (if you've used Tk, this should be very familiar).

```
set theYcoord [[$CQUAD cget -Node2] cget -y]
```

To make a variable be public, your class definition should say, for example:

```
public variable y
```

```
public {
    # Both x and y are to be public variables
    variable x
    variable y
}
```

I recommend keeping the number of public variables to a minimum, but that's your business.

Comment: using namespace which N1 i get: ::N1    So itcl::delete Node $::N1 should delete it, but I get: bad option node, should be one of.... Just for me: N1 is the object name, "Node" is the object type ?

Comment: To delete, 'object' is a literal string.  So for your case it would be:  itcl::delete object ::N1